# My attempt to create a simple Gantt chart (Table) using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I attempt to create a simple Gantt chart (Table):
[image]
I use computed property newTasks() to imitate the getting asynchronously a list of tasks from a Vuex Store but my solution doesn’t work.
Could you help me please.

Not working solution with computed property: https://jsfiddle.net/AlexPilugin/98b0pw24/

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    longMode: false,
    columns: 7,
    tasks: null
  },
  watch: {
    newTasks(val) {
      this.tasks = val;
      this.$forceUpdate();
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.tasks = this.newTasks;
      this.$forceUpdate();
    })
  },
  computed: {
    newTasks() {
      let tasks = null;
      console.log("newTasks-------------");
      const self = this;
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (self.longMode) {
          tasks = [{
              start: 0,
              end: 3
            },
            {
              start: 2,
              end: 9
            },
            {
              start: 7,
              end: 13
            }
          ];
        } else {
          tasks = [{
              start: 0,
              end: 4
            },
            {
              start: 2,
              end: 6
            }
          ];
        }
        console.log("return new tasks:");
        console.log(tasks);
        return tasks;
      }, 2000);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.longMode = !this.longMode;
      this.columns = this.longMode ? 14 : 7;
      this.tasks = this.newTasks;
      console.log("clicked! longMode: " + this.longMode);
    },
    getLineStyle(index) {
      let rowIndex = 2;
      console.log("getLineStyle(" + rowIndex + ")");
      console.log(this.$refs);
      if (this.tasks && this.tasks.length > 0) {
        console.log(this.tasks);
        let task = this.tasks[rowIndex];
        console.log(task);
        let start = task.start;
        let end = task.end;
        let startRef = 'cell' + start;
        let endRef = 'cell' + end;
        let startLeft = this.$refs[startRef][0].offsetLeft;
        let endLeft = this.$refs[endRef][0].offsetLeft;
        let taskWidth = (endLeft - startLeft) + 'px';
        let styleObject = {
          left: startLeft,
          width: taskWidth
        };
        return styleObject;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: auto;
  /*fixed;*/
  border: 1px solid #012656;
}

.cell {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #012656;
  cursor: pointer;
}

td.cell:nth-child(7n-1),
td.cell:nth-child(7n) {
  background: #eee;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="gantt-table">
    <tr @click="toggle">
      <td v-for="(cell, colIndex) in columns" :ref="'cell'+colIndex" :key="'col-'+colIndex" class="cell">
        {{ colIndex+1 }}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-show="tasks && tasks.length > 0" v-for="(row, rowIndex) in tasks" :key="'tr-'+rowIndex">
      <div style="position: relative;">
        <div class="line" :style="getLineStyle(rowIndex)"></div>
      </div>
      <td v-for="(cell, colIndex) in columns" :key="'row-'+rowIndex+'col-'+colIndex" class="cell">
        <div>&nbsp&nbsp</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Another approach (with method): https://jsfiddle.net/AlexPilugin/qxbd4gcw/

https://jsfiddle.net/AlexPilugin/98b0pw24/3/ - **Script is not drawing extra rows based on number of tasks (tasks.length)**
and rowIndex in getLineStyle(rowIndex) in undefined! Why?!!

Edit
[With Promise](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexPilugin/98b0pw24/28/)

**Why watch doesn't work?**.
**Why both solutions don't work:**
<tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in newTasks" ...> 
<tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in tasks" ..>

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools=false;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    longMode: false,
    columns: 7,
    tasks: []
  },
  created() {
    this.tasks = this.newTasks;
  },
  watch: {
    newTasks(tasks) {
      console.log("watch: newTasks()-------------");
      console.log(tasks);
      this.tasks = tasks;
      this.$forceUpdate();
    }
  },
  computed: {
    newTasks() {
      let tasks = null;
      if(this.longMode) {
        tasks = [
          {start: 0, end: 3},
          {start: 2, end: 9},
          {start: 7, end: 13}
        ];
      } else {
        tasks = [
          {start: 0, end: 4},
          {start: 2, end: 6}
        ];
      }
      this.delay(2000).then(() => {
        console.log("return new tasks:");
        console.log(tasks);
        return tasks;
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.longMode = !this.longMode;
      this.columns = this.longMode ? 14 : 7;
      this.tasks = this.newTasks;
      console.log("clicked! longMode: " + this.longMode);
    },
    delay(t) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, t)
      });
    },
    getLineStyle(index) {
      let rowIndex = 2;
      console.log("getLineStyle("+rowIndex+")");
      console.log(this.$refs);
      if(this.tasks && this.tasks.length>0) {
        console.log(this.tasks);
        let task = this.tasks[rowIndex];
        console.log(task);
        let start = task.start;
        let end = task.end;
        let startRef = 'cell'+start;
        let endRef = 'cell'+end;
        let startLeft = this.$refs[startRef][0].offsetLeft; 
        let endLeft = this.$refs[endRef][0].offsetLeft;
        let taskWidth = (endLeft - startLeft) + 'px';
        let styleObject = {left: startLeft, width: taskWidth};
        return styleObject;
      }
    }
  }
})
body {
background: #20262E;
padding: 20px;
font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
background: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 20px;
transition: all 0.2s;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
table-layout: auto;
/*fixed;*/
border: 1px solid #012656;
}

.cell {
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #012656;
cursor: pointer;
}

td.cell:nth-child(7n-1),
td.cell:nth-child(7n) {
background: #eee;
}

.line {
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
height: 6px;
border-radius: 3px;
background: red;
overflow: hidden;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table class="gantt-table">
    <tr @click="toggle">
      <td 
        v-for="(cell, colIndex) in columns" 
        :ref="'cell'+colIndex" 
        :key="'col-'+colIndex" 
        class="cell"
      >
        {{ colIndex+1 }}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr 
      v-show="newTasks && newTasks.length > 0" 
      v-for="(row, rowIndex) in newTasks" 
      :key="'tr-'+rowIndex"
    >
      <!--
      <div style="position: relative;">
        <div class="line" :style="getLineStyle(rowIndex)"></div>
      </div>  
      -->
      <td 
        v-for="(cell, colIndex) in columns" 
        :key="'row-'+rowIndex+'col-'+colIndex" 
        class="cell"
      >
        <div>&nbsp&nbsp</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: _"my solution doesn’t work"_  could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58090098/edit) and explain _how_ it's not working?

Comment: OK. Sorry. I will edit my question right now

Comment: I made your code into a runnable snippet. You should attend to the errors before continuing ~ _"Property or method "rowIndex" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"_

Comment: Hi Phil Thank you for your help. It looks great!
https://jsfiddle.net/AlexPilugin/98b0pw24/3/ - not drawing extra rows based on number of tasks (tasks.length)
and rowIndex in getLineStyle(rowIndex) in undefined! Why?!!

Comment: You should probably initialise `tasks` to be an empty array instead of `null`